# Make [unity2d] a synonym of [unity3d-2dtools]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, synonym-request

I noticed the tag [unity2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity2d) was created about a month ago.

Fortunately, there is already a tag to describe the 2d tools in Unity: [unity3d-2dtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-2dtools).

Honestly, neither of the two's wikis is very descriptive, but [unity3d-2dtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-2dtools)'s is slightly better.

Unity does not help us out here, referring to something called [unity2d](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Unity2D.html) in their docs, but really there is only one product, the thing we call [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d), which can toggle between two different modes/slightly different physics libraries. (but they're also the ones who refer to their non ECMA compliant unityscript language as javascript in the docs so...)

tl;dr:
I believe the newer tag, [unity2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity2d) should be made a synonym of [unity3d-2dtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-2dtools).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think this should be done.

[unity3d-2dtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-2dtools) is somewhat of a holdover from the Unity 4.x days, when built in 2D support in the engine was extremely limited and developers were required to obtain extensions to Unity, such as [2D Toolkit](http://www.2dtoolkit.com/features.html) to really be able to develop 2D games.  All the different tools that were used then could fit under the umbrella of that tag.

[unity2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity2d) is more in reference to the native 2D support that Unity provides now in 5.x.  There are no longer any external tools required.

It does seem as though the tag wiki of [unity3d-2dtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-2dtools) has drifted more towards what [unity2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity2d) should be recently.  It seems as though [unity3d-2dtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-2dtools) should be updated to indicate that it is mainly focused on tools made for use prior to Unity 5.x's native 2D support, and [unity2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity2d) should make it clear that it is focused on Unity's native 2D capabilities.

Comment: Interesting history, I did not know that. I literally started with unity the week those tools came out. The only thing I'm concerned about then is the lack of the main unity tag (unity3d) on unity2d questions. Maybe thats fine though.

Comment: I agree with Brien. This should not be done according to the explanation.